# Alt-s Javascript event handler in Firefox: How?

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom-events

I have a webapp which will be viewed using certain popular browsers and I am required to support the handling of certain keypress events.  Our users will be using Windows and the keypress events always use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key as a modifier.

There is no specific requirement for keyUp/keyDown event handling, the user just has to feel like something happens when he/she presses, for example, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>.

**How do we accomplish this in the Firefox browser, which we are required to support?**

**The problem:**
All of our implementation attempts are interfered-with by the fact that when the FireFox menu bar is visible (File, Edit...), pressing an <kbd>Alt</kbd> key combination which is already claimed by the menu bar (example: <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd>) will cause the appropriate menu to expand.  We don't want this to happen.  I have been shown examples of web apps (using tens of thousands of lines of javascript....) that do NOT experience this issue, so I know it is possible, but I don't know how this was done in the example I've seen with my own eyes.

I can find dozens of examples on the web of how to write an alt-key handler in JS, but I haven't found a single article on this issue or a single code example that works under the circumstances I've described.  We are using Spring-MVC and a recent version of jQuery, if that matters.

I'm happy to update the question with any other information that proves relevant.

Side note about work-around suggestions:
The requestor has specifically demanded that I use the Alt key as the modifier, on the grounds that they use other webapps in FireFox where both the menu-bar is visible AND <kbd>alt</kbd> key combinations work.  (Example: <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd>).  So, feel free to post well-intentioned work-arounds in the comment section if you wish - I promise that my own personal curiosity will drive me to read them all - but also keep in mind this is not the subject of my question.

Comment: Would it be a Firefox plugin an acceptable solution? Or disable the Firefox built-in Alt key command? Are you sure they are not using this kind of workarounds in the example you have seen?

Comment: I've personally used the webapp they want me to imitate (it's proprietary or I'd provide it here).  No plugins are used that FF doesn't ship with, and no FF configuration options are changed from default.  It "just works" for our users with standard FF 38.0.5.  Wish I knew how :)

Answer (score 1):

Hotkeys have been done well by various projects, such as [jquery.hotkeys](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys). You can see a [working example](https://rawgit.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys/master/test-static-01.html) on their demo page for most hotkeys. It's  [very small, only about 200 lines](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys/blob/master/jquery.hotkeys.js).

Here is a [small example with the Alt+S hotkey](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQeEMv) that works for me (without triggering the history menu) in Firefox 40.0.2 (when the page is in focus of course, not the codepen editor).

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'Alt+s', function() {
    $('body').append('Alt+s was pressed; ');
    // alert('alert will cause the menu to activate, do not use');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that some browsers will not allow you to capture certain shortcuts! A working example in native Javascript for the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> shortcut in Mozilla Firefox (*version: 51.0.1, Linux*):

```
window.onkeydown = function(e){
  if(e.altKey && e.keyCode == 83){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Shotcut Pressed")
  }
}
```